# tocify and url with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, url, tableofcontents, jquery-tocify-js

I am using [Tocify](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.tocify.js) to make a TOC for some content on my site.
Let's say my site is called `www.example.com` and I click an element in my TOC. The default option for Tocify is to change my url to `www.example.com?elementclicked`

But my site is `www.mysite.com/index.php?page=folder/test/ShowSite&tabid=1&site_id=87`.
If I click an element, it changes the url to `www.mysite.com?elementClicked`. How can I make it change the link to `www.mysite.com/index.php?page=folder/test/ShowSite&tabid=1&site_id=87?elementClicked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote Tocify and just updated [Tocify](https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.tocify.js) to v1.1.0, which no longer uses History.js or the HTML5 push state API for history management.  Instead, a hash is used (which should fix your issue).  Please grab the latest Tocify code and let me know if you have any other issues.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Appending current URL will automatically lead to page reloading. That can probably be tweaked by preventing page to auto-load but instead of adding `?elementClicked` you could add `#elementClicked` ...

```
window.location.hash = 'elementClicked';
```